# Drawed figure on canvas appears for a short moment, but then disappear

Tags: javascript, canvas, coffeescript

I want to draw star on canvas. I succeeded with constant value as below:

[image: スクリーンショット（2012-09-18 13.57.53）]

The source code is below:

```
line = (r, s, context) ->
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(250, 250)
    context.lineTo(
        250 + r * Math.cos(s * 2 * Math.PI),
        250 + r * Math.sin(s * 2 * Math.PI)
    )
    context.stroke()

window.onload = ->
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    context = canvas.getContext("2d")

    for i in [1..10]
        line(200, i / 10, context)
    return
```

On the next step, I tried to it able to set the number of lines.

[image: スクリーンショット（2012-09-18 14.13.45）]

The CoffeeScript source is below:

```
line = (r, s, context) ->
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(250, 250)
    context.lineTo(
        250 + r * Math.cos(s * 2 * Math.PI),
        250 + r * Math.sin(s * 2 * Math.PI)
    )
    context.stroke()

isInt = (n) ->
    (n % 1) == 0;

root = exports ? this
root.star = ->
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
    context = canvas.getContext("2d")
    n = document.fm.int.value
    if(isInt(n))
        for i in [1..n]
            line(200, i / n, context)
        return
    else
        alert("is not integer")
        return
```

The full html page source is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

    (function() {
      var isInt, line, root;

      line = function(r, s, context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(250, 250);
        context.lineTo(250 + r * Math.cos(s * 2 * Math.PI), 250 + r * Math.sin(s * 2 * Math.PI));
        return context.stroke();
      };

      isInt = function(n) {
        return (n % 1) === 0;
      };

      root = typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : this;

      root.star = function() {
        var canvas, context, i, n, _i;
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        n = document.fm.int.value;
        if (isInt(n)) {
          for (i = _i = 1; 1 <= n ? _i <= n : _i >= n; i = 1 <= n ? ++_i : --_i) {
            line(200, i / n, context);
          }
        } else {
          alert("is not integer");
        }
      };

    }).call(this);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="fm" onsubmit="star()">
        Integer: 
    <input type="text" name="int" size="5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Draw">
    </form>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then star appears for a short moment, but then the star disappear. How can I keep the star displayed?

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Because the form is submitted and the page is reloaded (due to the lack of `action` attribute)?

Answer (score 0):

**Better Answer Wanted**

Passerby told me a good advice.

below is old source:

```
<form name="fm" onsubmit="star()">
```

below is new source:

```
<form name="fm" action="javascript:star()">
```

This works very well. Thank you, Passerby. To tell the truth, I can not understand why this code works well and last code not...

[image: スクリーンショット（2012-09-18 14.44.34）]